# displaying SQL results on structured webpage

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, web, asp-classic

OK, got a bit of a conundrum here.

I've got an SQL query that i wan't to display on a webpage.
The problem I have is getting it to display the results in the format that is required.

It's essentially to be a weekly schedule of jobs, split into days, and grouped by each installation team. The number of jobs per day per team can vary from none to 3 or 4.
The SQL query pull of the job data from the base in a big list (as i would expect) - no problems there.

The conundrum is getting it to display on the webpage in the specific format - which is this

[image]

The webserver is a IIS windows server, but has PHP installed, so can use ASP/VB or PHP.

This is the query:

```
SELECT  Pers_Name
    ,   PER_Data7
    ,   Call_Ref
    ,   dbo.dateonly(Scheduled_Date_Time) AS sched_date
    ,   Link_to_Contract_Header
    ,   Add1
    ,   Add2
    ,   Post_Code
    ,   Call_Type_Description
    ,   LUCFC_Description
    ,   Call_Status_Description
FROM Calls WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Clients WITH (NOLOCK) ON Link_to_Client = Client_Ref
LEFT JOIN Personnel WITH (NOLOCK) ON Last_Allocated_To = Pers_Ref
LEFT JOIN LU_Call_Types WITH (NOLOCK) ON Call_Type = Call_Type_Code
LEFT JOIN Personnel_More WITH (NOLOCK) ON Last_Allocated_To = PER_Link_to_Pers_Ref
LEFT JOIN LU_Call_Fault_codes WITH (NOLOCK) ON call_fault_code_1 = LUCFC_Code
LEFT JOIN LU_Call_Status WITH (NOLOCK) ON Last_Event_Status = Call_Status_Code
WHERE dbo.dateonly(Scheduled_Date_Time) BETWEEN '5 August 2013' AND '11 August 2013'
    AND Call_Type IN ('BC', 'IN')
    AND PER_Data7 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY sched_date, PER_Data7
```

`PER_Data7` is the field that holds the team name (ie Team 1, Team 2 etc).
`sched_date` is the date of the job.

How to tackle this?

I have a working version that displays just a 1 day schedule, but the structure for that is completely different and very basic, and will be junked.

Comment: ASP/VBScript and PHP are different languages/frameworks - which is the rest of the site this is a part of programmed in?

Comment: i know they are different languages - i was simply stating what the server supports.

this will be a standalone page, and there is no other site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't studied your query and compared it to the table to verify that records are coming out in the order you want to display them, but I'll assume they are and I'll assume if they're not, that you know how to make those changes.

The basic idea, then, is to iterate over your results and output each field into an HTML table. I use ASP, so it would look something like this:

```
' Make the connection etc, then...
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 etc...."
Set recordSet = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
recordSet.Open cmdTemp, , adOpenKeyset, adLockReadonly

' If there are results, emit the table

if not recordSet.EOF then
    Response.Write "<table><tr><td><b>Heading1</b><td><b>Heading2</b></td>...</tr>"

    ' While there is another record to process, emit each row

    do while not recordSet.EOF
         Response.Write "<tr><td>" & recordSet("field1") & "</td><td>" & recordSet("field2") & "</td>...</tr>"

         ' Get the next record

         recordSet.MoveNext
    loop

    ' Finish the table

   Response.Write "</table>"
end if
```

If your question is more about how to structure your query, that might be too big of a question to post here. You may have to do multiple queries (one per row, one per column, or one per data cell in the table) depending on exactly how your table is structured and what you're trying to do.

Comment: no, they query is fine and it pulls all the data that is required for the weeks worth of jobs that are to be displayed.

it was getting it displaying in the structure required that was the tricky part.

looking at your code, i'm not sure that actually gives the structure that is required.
looks like it just multiple rows, and doesn't take into account 7 days and 10 teams in a table as per the attached image.

Comment: Yeah, and it also doesn't fill in the background color in the header cells. So what you're saying is that you don't know anything about HTML at all and need every detail? I was just showing how ASP/VBScript and HTML can be integrated to do what you  need. I assumed you could pick it up from there. See w3schools.com for HTML tutorials.

Comment: think you have misunderstood the question Craig and you seem to have taken the hump.

the example you gave i already knew how to do. it was the specific layout that i showed that i was looking for assistance on.

thanks for your response though, but it seems you have taken the hump for some reason so feel free to contribute nothing more.

Comment: It might be easier if you order by per_data7, sched_date. You're going to want the data for each team so you can fill out the rows, then the data for each day so you can fill in the columns for each row. What goes in each cell? I can't figure that out from the question. And no idea what "taken the hump" means.